# How to increase width of textbox inside navbar-form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently create my search-box inside my navbar like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5">
     <div class="navbar-form" role="search">
         <div class="input-group">
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <div class="input-group-btn">
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSearch" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="search_click" runat="server"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This method gives the following result:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDywH.png]

However, I want the search-box to be extended between "Add a website" and "Register" and centered, leaving approximately 20px margin on each side. For some reason `navbar-form` doesnt allow the width to grow beyond a certain point. What can I do to fix this problem? As soon as I remove `navbar-form` and replace with for example `form-group`, the formatting and margins to top and bottom is all wrong.

EDIT: Navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/Default.aspx" class="navbar-brand">Logogo</a>

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/AddSite.aspx">Add a website</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5">
                        <div class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSearch" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="search_click" runat="server"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li >
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRegister" runat="server" OnClick="Register">Register</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" runat="server">Log in</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogout" runat="server" OnClick="Logout">Log out</asp:LinkButton></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can u show us the css and recreate it in a fiddle if you can

Comment: I tried bootply but cant get it to load, what others are there?

Comment: here you go [http://www.bootply.com/OOKdKt2StC](http://www.bootply.com/OOKdKt2StC)

Comment: First time trying to use bootply but for some reason it does not load properly. My searchbar doesnt even show and the links are standard html. So I uploaded the code to my questions instead, hope that will do

Comment: For now I have changed it to using `form-group` instead of `navbar-form` and added a top margin of 10px. However this makes the navbar a bit "fatter" and its a pretty ugly solution so I would still appriciate the answer.